# добавление прошедшего времени в список

Tags: python

как можно добавить в список все прошедшие часы ?
то есть если сейчас 18:50 хотелось бы иметь вывод вида

```
[1:00, 2:00, ... , 17:00, 18:00]
```

Comment: `список = ['{}:00'.format(x) for x in range(1, datetime.datetime.now().hour + 1)]`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! можете оформить ввиде ответа